# Issue on Removing A Table Row Which All <td> has a Specific Class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can you please take a look at [This Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/8tsdouys/) and let me know how I can remove Only the `<tr>` which all of it's `<td>` has `.old` class?

I tried this code to do the job

```
$("#removeOld").on("click",function(){
  $('tbody').find('tr').each(function () {

    var rows = 0;
    var rows_old = 0;

    $(this).find('td').each(function () {
        rows++;
        if ($(this).has('old')) rows_old++;
    });

    if (rows === rows_old) $(this).remove();
});
});
```

but this is removing the whole table! can you please let me know what I am doing wrong and how I can fix this?

Thanks

Comment: `.hasClass()` instead of `.has()`. Helps to read the docs. Though it would be simpler if you just did `if (this.cells.length === $(this).find("td.old").length) $(this).remove();`

Comment: Please include HTML in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to delete `tr` which does not have a `td` which is not `td.old` so

```js
$("#removeOld").on("click", function() {
  $('tbody tr').not(':has(td:not(.old))').remove()
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="removeOld" type="button">Remove Entire Old Row!</button>
<table style="width:100%">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="old">Some Old</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>All New</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="old">Some Old</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="old">All Old</td>
      <td class="old">Smith</td>
      <td class="old">50</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```